# Exporting Custom Display Suite View Modes With Configuration

Tags: display-suite, configuration

I'm using [display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) with custom display settings for several view modes.  I am also using the [configuration management](https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration) module for D7.

When I go to import my config on the staging server, the content types and settings and even the 'ds' field format settings come through, but it does not remember what view modes I've checked to have custom display settings.  If I manually go back in and recheck the view modes, everything displays fine again.

Any idea where to track those changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  It is under the strongarm variables.  The setting you have to click is field_bundle_settings for that particular content type.  You must have the [strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) module enabled for this to work.